# How to disable postgresql port for out-server connection?

Tags: nginx, docker, postgresql

I installed on my dedicated server ubuntu 20.04, docker, and container with postgressql.
I have problem beacouse I want that ubuntu blocked all connection with postgressql, out-server from domain, ip server etc, which added to server.

At the moment I can connect with PostgreSQL:

- via ssh
- via server ip. ip.ip.ip:5432/...
- via all domain which added to nginx like domain1.com:5432 etc.

I want disabled connection via server ip and all domain which added to nginx

Comment: If postgresql is running in a container, and your don't want to have it accessable on the outside, why do you expose the port in the first place?

Comment: don't expose port inside your docker container or if you have to then control the access on firewall or whatever is in front i believe.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I expose the port to another container. 
How I can expose port only local inside in machine?

plastikman156 can you explain more?

Comment: @plastikman156 can you explain more?

Comment: If you only want to access postgres from another container then link them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@mxcdh If you want your postgres container to be accessible from other docker container you don't need to expose the port, just put both containers in same docker network.